# How many 4 digits numbers are divisible by 9, can only include the digits 3,6, and 9, and can only have three max of the same digit?

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the total possiblity for four digit numbers is 9000, but how do I find the amount of four digit numbers that satisfy the requirements above?

Here is the original problem:
There are 9000 distinct 4-digit positive integers. If we add restrictions to the make up of the numbers, then the number of possible 4-digit numbers may be
reduced.
How many 4-digit numbers can be created given the following restrictions?
• The only digits that can be used are 3, 6 and 9.
• A specific digit can occur at most three times in the number.
• The number must be divisible by 9.

Comment: If you have a numer (a bunch of digits), how could you quickly see if it's divisible by $9$ ?

Comment: Through adding the digits up, but I'm looking to see how many 4 digit numbers satisfy the constraints. Thanks though!

Comment: Although I hate breaking into cases, here it is not so bad... Recognize that there are really only the possibilities `3339`, `3366`, `3699`, `6669` and their permutations.  Convince yourself why this is this case.  This gives a total of $4+6+12+4 = 26$

Comment: it's good problem.i'd like to see solution w/o casework bashing.

Comment: If you want to avoid casework bashing... then just choose the first three digits and don't give any care at all as to what they are.  There is only one choice for the fourth digit that makes the sum and thus the number itself divisible by $9$.  Now... remove the offending cases, which would have occurred if strictly more than three of the digits is the same, i.e. all four digits are the same, which we see is a multiple of $9$ only in the case that all four of the digits were $9$ itself... giving an answer of $3^3-1=26$

Comment: If it is divisible by 9, it's sum of digits must be divisible by 9. Take it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the comments to an answer...

Remember that a number is divisible by $9$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $9$.

Begin by choosing any three digits to begin your number with.  Once those three digits were selected, regardless what they are, there will always be exactly once choice for the final digit such that the overall final number will be divisible by $9$.  There are $3^3=27$ ways to accomplish this first step, seen easily by rule of product.

Now... let us remove the offending cases where we had ignored the condition that we were only allowed a maximum of three of a particular digit.  Had we failed that condition, that means all four of the digits were the same.  But, if all digits were the same *and* the number were divisible by nine, that could only have happened with our available digits in the case that all of the digits were $9$ itself... so there was only one "bad" number that we didn't want to count, namely $9999$.

Subtracting this one offending case from our count leaves us with a total of $3^3-1=26$

---

Had we approached directly from cases, it is quick to see that the only possibilities are `3339`,`3366`,`3699`, and `6669` and their permutations, which would have yielded a count of $4+6+12+4=26$, same result as we had before.

Comment: Neat. So you avoided casework after all!